# Exposing external assembly class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I just can't wrap my head around this problem.

I'm using an external DLL, which includes a custom type class. If I bind my i.e. dataGrid to the ObservableCollection using ItemsSource, and set `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />` it results in an empty cell. If I do `<DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding .}" />` it shows me the *NameSpace.externalClass* Type.

I got it working with declaring myExternalClass like so:

```
public class myExternalClass
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Comment { get; private set; }

    public myExternalClass(externalClass ec)
    {
        Name = ec.Name;
        Comment = ec.Comment;
    }
}
```

This is how my property looks like:

```
    private ObservableCollection<myExternalClass> _dataSets;

    public ObservableCollection<myExternalClass> DataSets
    {
        get { return _dataSets; }
        set
        {
            if (_dataSets!= value)
            {
                _dataSets= value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => DataSets);
            }
        }
    }
```

So with that I have to iterate over the objects of the original externalClass and create instances with them of myExternalClass. It works like that but there has to be a proper way of doing it, right? How can I expose the external class without writing a "wrapper" class around it?

I'm implementing a MVVM pattern (caliburn.micro) in this wpf program for the first time, too. It got a bit of a steep learning curve ;(

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I can even access the values directly like this:

```
        externalDataManager = new externalDataManager();
        _dataSets = new ObservableCollection<externalClass>(externalDataManager.EnumDataSets(false));
        Debug.Assert(false, _dataSets[0].Name);
```

And the Assert is showing me the right value, using the original externalClass. Why does it fail when binding the Collection to some control in the view?

**Edit2:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="FirstMVVM.Views.ShellView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FirstMVVM.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataSets, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MinWidth="340" Margin="23,37,12,95" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comment" Binding="{Binding Comment}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

        <ComboBox x:Name="DataSets" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The amount of rows in the datagrid and the number of elements in the combobox are correct, they are just empty values.

Comment: has property Name a value?

Comment: Yes, it has a value.

Comment: You haven't shared the xaml where you are facing difficulty.

Comment: Sorry, I just added the xaml.